# Filter and replace an attribute name with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have this JSON:

```
{name:attr:MyDescription, value:TEST_DESCRIPTION}
{name:attr:MyVersion, value:TEST_VERSION}
```

I need to print the value of "name" attribute without the "attr:" prefix.
I want to print "MyDescription" and "MyVersion" and not "attr:MyDescription" & "attr:MyVersion".

I've wrote a filter and I've tried to result the single element with item.name.replace('attr:','') but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to handle this kind of situation with Angular JS?

Comment: Do you get this JSON from a server or something? If the JSON is valid (correctly escaped) your solution should work.

Comment: `{[]}:?` should be escaped with a ` \  `

Comment: @Iansen, yep, the JSON comes from a server and it is valid. Debugging the code it works, but the result in the template is the old one, I can't understand why... this is the very simple filter I wrote:

$scope.attributesFilter = function(item) {
  return item.name.replace("prop:","");
}

Comment: Can you please share the fiddle link. The question is not very clear from the description above.